# PHP While Loop logic

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, post

Can you Help me?? I am trying for some validation in my system, but I got stuck up on my ideas.

I created a text box that will looped when you enter any number. When the text box appear the user will have to fill up names, but if the user accidentally type a duplicated name the prompt message will appear saying: "Errors".

There is minor bug in my system and I want to fix it. I have think a lot of methods but this is the best fit to my system.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="fq1.php" method="post">    

    <input type="text" name="num" id="num">
    <input type="submit" value="select" name="select" id="select" />    

    <?php include 'conectthis.php';
        $num = $_POST['num'];

        if(isset($_POST['select']))
        {
            $x = 0;
            while($x <= $num)
            {
                $x++;
                echo "<input type='text' name='txt".$x."' />";
            }
            echo "<input type='submit' name='save' id='save' value='Save'>";
        }
        if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {
            $y = 0;
            while($y<=$num)
            {
                $y++;
                $mypost1 = "txt". $y;

                if($_POST[$mypost1] == $_POST[$mypost1])
                {
                    $prompts = "<script>alert('Names was not saved, please ensure that there are no duplicated Names');</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $runthis = "Update sampletable SET samplename = '$_POST[$mypost1]' WHERE id = '$y'";
                    mysql_query($runthis) or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
            echo $prompts;
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Now my problem is `if($_POST[$mypost1] == $_POST[$mypost1])` the textbox will recognize it self and show the prompt message even there is no duplicated name(s).

It's a scratch from my code I think I know it is right.
Thank you in advance, I am new to this and still studying.

Comment: Why while loops? For-loops seem more appropriate. You are also always comparing a single textbox's value to itself, which will always result in the alert showing. As for checking for duplicates, I would simply load up all of the textbox values in an array and check for duplicates with any number of built-in array helper functions.

Comment: You code seems to be missing a closing curly brace, but anyway, this line `$runthis = "Update sampletable SET samplename = '$_POST[$mypost1]' WHERE id = '$y'";` is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Also, `$_POST[$mypost1] == $_POST[$mypost1]` will always return `true`, they are the same variable.